# Convert .crl to .pem format with openssl

Tags: linux, openssl

I'm trying to convert my .crl file into a .pem on my Red Hat server with openssl but it fails with:

```
openssl crl -in lab-rootca-ca.crl -inform DER -out lab-rootca-ca.crl.pem
unable to load CRL
139996682680136:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1343:
139996682680136:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:393:Type=X509_CRL
```

I see that the format is x509 but the inform flag doesn't support it.  What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the .crl file is encoded in DER? It should have binary data when opened with a (hex) editor. If it is textual BASE64 encoded, then it is in PEM format.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked: openssl crl -in lab-rootca-ca.crl -inform PEM -out lab-rootca-ca.crl.pem

Comment: Is this even necessary? The file is already in PEM format, a simple file copy would have the same effect? Just compare both files and see if there are any differences: `diff lab-rootca-ca.crl lab-rootca-ca.crl.pem`, I would be surprised if there were any.